# Show/Hide specific columns based on checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets, show-hide

So I have to sheets/panes in a Google Sheet. My "Settings"-sheet includes a number of checkboxes.

What I want, is to be able to show/hide specific columns in my second sheet, based on the true/false state of these checkboxes.

Idea is that each checbox will correspond to a specific column in the second sheet.

I know how to do this in Excel, but I have virtually NO experience in Google Apps Script, other than what I have been able to Google this morning.

Can anyone help me by pointing me on the right path?

For reference, the Visual Basics script I use for the same function in Excel is included below:

```
Private Sub CheckBox17_Click()
['Competitive Matrix (EMEA NE)'!S:S].EntireColumn.Hidden = Not CheckBox17
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a bit more verbose than Visual Basic version :)

```
function hideColumns() {
  // takes active spreadsheet (the one the script is bound to) into work
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var settingsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Settings'); // insert your sheet name here
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  // gets values from all the cells in the settings sheet into a two-dimensional array, like [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
  var values = settingsSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
  for (var i in values) {
    // checks every row of data if the value in first column is false or not
    if (values[i][0] == 'false') { 
      // my assumption is that each of your checkboxes is on a new line; 
      // hideColumn will hide those columns that correspond to rows to in the settings sheet
      dataSheet.hideColumn(dataSheet.getRange(1, i)); 
    }
  }
}
```

Google Apps Script have very good documentation regarding almost all of their services, SpreadsheetApp is covered pretty well, check out these pages about the functions used above:

[hideColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn)

[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

UPD:
version using `onEdit` function — it looks at the edited cell and checks if it is in the first column of "Settings" sheet and if the new value is `true`. If it all is true, it'll hide the column in "Data" that corresponds to the edited row.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var dataSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Data');
  var currentSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if (currentSheet === 'Settings' && col === 1 && e.value.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
    dataSheet.hideColumn(dataSheet.getRange(1, row));
  }
}
```

More to read about `e` object in `onEdit` functions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and inputs - will definately check those links out :)

Just a few quick follow-ups:

1) The column in "Settings" with the checkboxes is actually the third one, so I'm guessing it would be:

if (values[i][3] == 'false')?

2) I need this function/script to be constantly checking and updating the values.
Do I need to use an "OnEdit" trigger for this, or how do I do that?
Currently it does not seem to update automatically.

Comment: `getValues` presents the data as js-array which are 0-based (yep, I made an error in the example, will fix it now), so 3rd column is going to be `values[i][2]` (beware that `getRange` function is different in this respect and to get value of the cell in the first row and third column you'll use `getRange(1, 3).getValue()` — just in case). 
As for tracking changes — yes, you should try `onEdit` in this case.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to change the function to onEdit () or do I need to make an installable trigger?

Comment: if you're tracking changes only in current spreadsheet, then plain onEdit is ok, you'd need an installable trigger to look for changes in other spreadsheet(s) via a code in different one.

Comment: Thanks for the update, which seems way simpler :) - I do still get an error though from line 2:

TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (linje 2, fil "SHowHideColumns")

Comment: if you're trying to run `onEdit` from script editor, it'll always return an error because `e` is always going to be undefined. Try editing a cell in your spreadsheet (and maybe throw in a few `Logger.log` into the function to check what's going on, they'll fire in simple triggers, like `onEdit`, too)